# Sprite moves into the "rotation direction" but my sprite is by default 90 degrees rotated to the right

Tags: math, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, macos

I have a sprite. I'm moving it into the direction where it faces to.

I move them in my tick method.

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt {
    for (CCBullet *bullet in bullets) {

    float angle  = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(bullet.rotation+90);

        bullet.position = ccp(bullet.position.x+sin(angle) * bullet.speed, bullet.position.y+cos(angle) * bullet.speed);
    }
}
```

If the rotation is 0 my sprite faces to the right. So the bullet should move to the right..
but it moves up.

I don't want to rotate the image file. Any alternative?

EDIT: Solved. Edited code.